# How to handle ajax post response sent form express server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm a beginner so I don't know if I was clear with my question.
My problem is that the response I send from my express server shows in the page but I can't handle it in my client side using jQuery.

Server-side:

```
router.post("/", [
    //check inputs using expres-validator
    ],
    (req, res)=>{
        //handle validation results
        var errors = validationResult(req);
         if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            //filter errors
            res.status(400).send([usernameErr, emailErr, passwordErr]);
        }else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        };
});
```

client-side:

```
$(".form-div form input[type='submit']").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parent().parent().attr("id") == "signup-form-container"){
            $.post('/signup', $('#signup-form-container form').serialize())
            .done(data=>{
                alert(data)
                console.log(data);
            })
            .fail((err, textStatus)=>{
                alert(err)
                console.log(err)
            });
            
        };
    });
```

I'm exporting my signup file, which have the route above, to my main file.

```
app.use("/signup", require(`${__dirname}/routes/signup.js`));
```

Comment: `.done(data=>{
                alert(data)
                console.log(data);
            })` is the part where you get the response and treat it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you check your selector:

```
$(".form-div form input[type='submit']") // this is selecting the input element
```

However, the submit event only fires when it is inside the form element, 
so attaching the submit event to buttons, or inputs will not work.

Here is the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

So, to solve the problem, try this:

```
/*
 Here you are selecting the form, so submitting here will work. 
*/
$(".form-div form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parent().parent().attr("id") == "signup-form-container"){
            $.post('/signup', $('#signup-form-container form').serialize())
            .done(data=>{
                alert(data)
                console.log(data);
            })
            .fail((err, textStatus)=>{
                alert(err)
                console.log(err)
            });

        };
    });
```

That's the reason that click was working because that fires when you click the element. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't work, it keeps on logging the response to the page and not to the console.

Comment: Can you show your '/signup/ route? I only see the route for '/' , because in your jquery you are making http post to '/signup/' route . Thanks

Comment: I edited the question. The `/` is the `/signup` route.

Comment: The problem wasn't in my server-side code, it was in the client-side: I should call the `click` event instead of the `submit` event on my `$(".form-div form input[type='submit']")`. I don't know why so if you had any idea, I would appreciate it if you share it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, could you show me your html ? that way I can see better how your form is structured. so I'm not that familiar with jquery, but are you just selecting the input element and attaching a submit event to it? . showing the code in an online editor will help alot if that's possible.  I can also show you a better and easier way to do it with the fetch api.

Comment: I edited the post, let me know if that makes sense and try it what I said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192683/discussion-between-eye-patch-and-german).